# Is packet forwarding possible on Android?

Tags: android, routes, packet, forwarding

Our requirement is to develop an Android App &/or service that does the following. Listen to http (port 80) requests/packets sent from the device (by any app). forward them to a different server and not to the host that they are meant to go to.

Can someones please indicate whether this is possible and if yes, then how?

Comment: Hi I am also facing some problem, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As android is a Linux system you might want to check redirection by using its iptables. However I assume that you might need root rights to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible on android versions 4.0 or greater with [VPNService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html). Have a look at the [ToyVpn](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/) example provided by google. It's not *nice* for the user as they get a popup and a constant icon on the notification bar, but it's possible.

If you only want port 80 you will have to decode the ip and tcp headers in your app.